# Any idea how to use Jmeter for performance testing of Standalone Java app?

Tags: java, jmeter

Any idea how to use Jmeter for performance testing of Standalone Java app???

thanks

Answer (score 2):

JMeter is used for simulating network traffic to a server and testing the responsiveness of the other end in heavy loads situations. It will be of some use for you, if your application exposes a network interface (HTTP, TCP, FTP, SOAP). Then you could add a "Sampler" and configure a scenario, where a lot of requests will be sent at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to [use a junit test in jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If you standalone app makes any HTTP Requests, then yes you can use JMeter to do a performance test for that. You can find out the HTTP Requests your app makes and add them in HTTP Request Sampler in Jmeter Test Plan and also add necessary data to it and then you can generate the load for that.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this for benchmarking standalone applications - https://github.com/openjdk/jmh